# Symmetry matrix Q or rank(Q-I)=1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

An orthogonal matrix $Q$ that satisfies rank$(Q-I)=1$ is called symmetry.

Based on my research, orthogonal matrices map a vector to another vector where "length" is preserved. It also preserves the angle between two vectors.

What I don't or can't imagine is the significance and geometric interpretation of symmetries. May I ask for help? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

A symmetry, as defined in this manner, is a mirroring of $\Bbb R^n$ across a subspace of dimension $n-1$. For instance,
$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}
$$
is a mirroring of $\Bbb R^3$ across the $xy$-plane

Comment: when you say "mirroring", does it mean "projection?"

Comment: @rrp_PH No, the only orthogonal projection is the identity. I mean mirroring.